# Como carregar ou descarregar pontos no Google Maps ao clicar em uma div?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps

Tenho uma página que mostra os trajetos percorridos por um veículo. Os trajetos serão mostrados em uma lista ordenada organizada horizontalmente ao estilo da Timestack timeline (http://isaaccambron.com/timestack/), exceto que não ficarão em cima uns dos outros, mas sim lado a lado, organizados de acordo com horário em que ocorreram. Para cada trajeto, será criado um item de lista e eu gostaria que quando o usuário clicasse em um trajeto (um botão colorido com o número do trajeto), os pontos do trajeto (que serão guardados em um array multidimensional) fossem mostrados no mapa e a div fosse destacada/selecionada. Quando o usuário clicar em outro trajeto, seleciona-se outra div, mostram-se outros pontos no mapa e a div anterior "perde" a seleção e os pontos daquela div são tirados do mapa.

Eu procurei na internet e não achei nenhuma biblioteca que tenha essa funcionalidade específica. Se alguém puder me dar alguma direção.

Acredito que para mostrar os pontos no mapa ou parar de mostrar os pontos anteriores, eu vou ter que usar AJAX, correto?

Comment: Já li e reli sua pergunta algumas vezes e juro q ainda não entendi oq vc precisa, só entendi q uma api pode resolver seu problema. Poderia explicar melhor o que precisa ser feito da parte técnica?

Answer (score 2):

Eu indico para você dar uma olhada -> [gmaps.js](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/)

Não tenho certeza se irá resolver seu problema, mas para todas as aplicações envolvendo o google maps que eu precisei desenvolver até hoje essa API deu conta, além do fato que é super simples trabalhar com ela.

Obs: Ví que você comentou sobre uso de AJAX. Eu tive muitos problemas com uso de AJAX com o maps, então fica a dica caso precise: deixe o mapa fixo apenas sendo carregando uma única vez no load da página, e depois apenas trabalhe adicionando/reposicionando/removendo os markers(pontos) nele.

õ/

Comment: Obrigado, parece muito boa, acredito que vai servir!